# pass constant to skaffold

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, skaffold

I am trying to use a constant in skaffold, and to access it in skaffold profile:

example `export SOME_IP=199.99.99.99 && skaffold run -p dev`

skaffold.yaml

```
...
deploy:
  helm:
    flags:
      global:
      - "--debug" 
    releases:
    - name: ***
      chartPath: ***
      imageStrategy:
        helm:
          explicitRegistry: true
      createNamespace: true
      namespace: "***"
      setValueTemplates:
        SKAFFOLD_SOME_IP: "{{.SOME_IP}}"
```

and in dev.yaml profile I need somehow to access it,
something like:
`{{ .Template.SKAFFOLD_SOME_IP }}`  and it should be rendered as `199.99.99.99`

I tried to use skaffold **envTemplate** and **setValueTemplates** fields, but could not get success, and could not find any example on web

Comment: Hi Binzari Catalin! As I understand, you want to use that variable in the kubernetes helm template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically found a solution which I truly don't like, but it works:

in **dev** profile: **values.dev.yaml** I added a placeholder

```
  _anchors_:
    - &_IPAddr_01 "<IPAddr_01_TAG>" # will be replaced with SOME_IP
```

The **<IPAddr_01_TAG>** will be replaced with const **SOME_IP** which will become **199.99.99.99** at the skaffold run

Now to run skaffold I will do:

```
export SOME_IP=199.99.99.99
sed -i "s/<IPAddr_01_TAG>/$SOME_IP/g" values/values.dev.yaml
skaffold run -p dev
```

so after the above sed, in **dev** profile: **values.dev.yaml**, we will see the SOME_IP const instead of placeholder

```
  _anchors_:
    - &_IPAddr_01 "199.99.99.99"
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the `SKAFFOLD_SOME_IP` variable that you have set in your skaffold.yaml you can write the chart `template` for Kubernetes Deployment like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
        image: {{ .Values.image }}
        env:
        - name: SKAFFOLD_SOME_IP
          value: "{{ .Values.SKAFFOLD_SOME_IP }}"
```

This will create an environment variable `SKAFFOLD_SOME_IP` for Kubernetes pods. And you can access it using 'go', for example, like this:

```
os.Getenv("SKAFFOLD_SOME_IP")
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it does not solve the problem.   
Scope is to access a constant in a skaffold profile.